# Render razor view to string without munging the html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I've previously found answers on how to render an MVC 4 view to a string. However, I started using **Visual Studio 2013** and now the result is not as expected. See below.

```
 <$A$><$B$> <$C$> class="panel"<$D$>> <$E$> class="cover-wrapper"<$F$>> <$G$> href="     
 <$H$>/book/<$I$><$J$>1<$K$><$L$>/<$M$>"<$N$>><$O$> src="<$P$>http://www.
 example.com/images/image.jpg<$Q$>"<$R$> class="cover"<$S$> /> <$T$> href="<$U$>
 <$V$>"<$W$> target="_blank"<$X$> rel="nofollow"<$Y$> class="amazon-button"<$Z$>> <$a$> 
 class="amazon-cart"<$b$>> Link → 
 <$c$> class="content"<$d$>>..........
```

The code being used is this:

```
    public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Any idea as to why all the letters and dollar signs are showing up now or how I need to change my code to get it to give me usable html?

Comment: When you upgraded to Visual Studio 2013, did you also change the .NET Framework version targeted by your project (e.g., from 4.0 to 4.5 or from 4.5 to 4.5.1)?.

Comment: @DanM I didn't change anything. Just opened it from source control, added the DLLs reinstalled some packages. Do I need to do that?

Comment: Jed, no, I was only asking because it seems more likely you'd get a change like that if you had changed the .NET Framework version. Visual Studio is just an environment for writing/editing/compiling, if no code/libraries/frameworks have changed, you should get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a bug I ran into during the summer, see bug report and response from Microsoft here [bug and workaround](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794142/vs2013-preview-viewengineresult-render-returning-malformed-html). Good news is that according to MS it should be fixed when VS2013 is released.

Workaround is to disable the browser link feature see here [browser link feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx.)