# MVC 5 Render View to String

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

It seems, most code for rendering view into string doesn't work in MVC 5.

I have latest MVC 5.1.2 templates and I am trying to render view into string.

```
    public static String RenderViewToString(ControllerContext context, String viewPath, object model = null)
    {
        context.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, viewPath, null);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, context.Controller.ViewData, context.Controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(context, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Well, it's working but its output contains lots of $ marks instead tags. I read something about it was fixed in RC version, but that's old news.

Problem looks like this

```
<$A$><h1></h1> 
<table</$A$><$B$> class=""</$B$><$C$>> <tbody</$C$><$D$></$D$><$E$>></tbody>
</table></$E$>
```

I would like to ask, how do you render views into string in latest MVC 5 template ?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387499/render-razor-view-to-string-without-munging-the-html?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok, seems I found a solution. Author of the idea is Yakir Manor.

```
class FakeController : ControllerBase
{
    protected override void ExecuteCore() { }
    public static string RenderViewToString(string controllerName, string viewName, object viewData)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);
            var fakeControllerContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "http://google.com", null), new HttpResponse(null))), routeData, new FakeController());
            var razorViewEngine = new RazorViewEngine();
            var razorViewResult = razorViewEngine.FindView(fakeControllerContext, viewName, "", false);

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(fakeControllerContext, razorViewResult.View, new ViewDataDictionary(viewData), new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
            razorViewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);
            return writer.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

It's a trick with fake context and response.

Example:

```
String renderedHTML = RenderViewToString("Email", "MyHTMLView", myModel );
```

My file MyHTMLView.cshtml is stored in Views/Email/MyHTMLView.cshtml. Email is a fake controller name.

Comment: hello, i tried this solutions it works fine for normal views . but not working for views inside area, any idea what to do with that getting this error 

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: view

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: view 

on var viewContext = new ViewContext...

Comment: @Alok, don't know if you found a solution yet, but I had a similar problem recently, and found that the controller action that was initiating this "RenderViewToString" call was not being initiated with fully qualified action name. It was missing the area. I was doing a post from a form that only had the controller and action name and not the area name as part of the form action.

Comment: @Hopeless yes i found my solution and i even made it work with sessions, which this function is not doing i will post it soon

Comment: @Alok are you still planning on sharing your solution? I would love to see it and it'd help the discussion here. Thanks!

Comment: @Hopeless posting it now... :)

Comment: @Hopeless you can check my method now, let me know if it have any performance penalties ;)

Comment: I am getting this exception: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: httpContext' at razorViewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);

Comment: You also need to check if your HttpContext.Current is null and if so assign it to the fake Http Context you created above

Answer (score 10):

following is the solution that works with session and areas on MVC5.

```
public class FakeController : ControllerBase
{
    protected override void ExecuteCore() { }
    public static string RenderViewToString(string controllerName, string viewName,string areaName, object viewData,RequestContext rctx)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                var routeData = new RouteData();
                routeData.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);
                routeData.Values.Add("Area", areaName);
                routeData.DataTokens["area"] = areaName;

                var fakeControllerContext = new ControllerContext(rctx, new FakeController());
                //new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "http://google.com", null), new HttpResponse(null))), routeData, new FakeController());
                fakeControllerContext.RouteData = routeData;

                var razorViewEngine = new RazorViewEngine();

                var razorViewResult = razorViewEngine.FindView(fakeControllerContext, viewName, "", false);

                var viewContext = new ViewContext(fakeControllerContext, razorViewResult.View, new ViewDataDictionary(viewData), new TempDataDictionary(), writer);

                razorViewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);
                return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
                //use example
                //String renderedHTML = RenderViewToString("Email", "MyHTMLView", myModel );
                //where file MyHTMLView.cstml is stored in Views/Email/MyHTMLView.cshtml. Email is a fake controller name.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do your exception handling here
        }
    }
}
```

here is how you call this from another controller

```
var modal = getModal(params);
return FakeController.RenderViewToString(controllerName, viewName, areaName, modal, this.Request.RequestContext);
```

using requestcontext we can easily pass current session in fakecontroller and render razor string.

Comment: glad to be of help @asemmokllati

Answer (score 3):

I had an immediate need to return 6 partial views as strings in a JSON object.  Instead of creating a static method, and passing all the unneeded parameters, I decided to add protected methods to our ControllerBase class that derives from Controller, and is used as the base class for all of our controllers.

Here is a fully functional ControllerBase class that provides this functionality, and works very similar to the PartialView() and View() methods that are in the Controller class.  It includes the additions from @Alok.

```
public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    #region PartialViewToString

    protected string PartialViewToString(string partialViewName, object model = null)
    {
        ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(Request.RequestContext, this);

        return ViewToString(
            controllerContext,
            ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName) ?? throw new FileNotFoundException("Partial view cannot be found."),
            model
        );
    }

    #endregion

    #region ViewToString

    protected string ViewToString(string viewName, object model = null)
    {
        ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(Request.RequestContext, this);

        return ViewToString(
            controllerContext,
            ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, null) ?? throw new FileNotFoundException("View cannot be found."),
            model
        );
    }

    protected string ViewToString(string viewName, string controllerName, string areaName, object model = null)
    {
        RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);

        if (areaName != null)
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("Area", areaName);
            routeData.DataTokens["area"] = areaName;
        }

        ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(HttpContext, routeData, this);

        return ViewToString(
            controllerContext,
            ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, null) ?? throw new FileNotFoundException("View cannot be found."),
            model
        );
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private string ViewToString(ControllerContext controllerContext, ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult, object model)
    {
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                controllerContext,
                viewEngineResult.View,
                new ViewDataDictionary(model),
                new TempDataDictionary(),
                writer
            );

            viewEngineResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);

            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@wh1sp3r answer works but for partial views I had to do the following minor changes:

```
 string html = FakeController.RenderViewToString("**Controllername**", "~/views/**Controllername**/_AsdfPartialPage.cshtml", fem);


public static string RenderViewToString(string controllerName, string viewName, object viewData)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);
            var fakeControllerContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "http://localhost", null), new HttpResponse(null))), routeData, new FakeController());
            var razorViewEngine = new RazorViewEngine();
            //var razorViewResult = razorViewEngine.FindView(fakeControllerContext, viewName, "", false);

            var razorViewResult = razorViewEngine.FindPartialView(fakeControllerContext, viewName,  false);

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(fakeControllerContext, razorViewResult.View, new ViewDataDictionary(viewData), new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
            razorViewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);
            return writer.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To render PartialView to string use this code:

```
class FakeController: ControllerBase {
    protected override void ExecuteCore() { }
    public static string RenderViewToString(string controllerName, string viewName, object model) {
        using(var writer = new StringWriter()) {
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);
            var fakeControllerContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "http://localhost", null), new HttpResponse(null))), routeData, new FakeController());
            var razorViewEngine = new RazorViewEngine();
            var razorViewResult = razorViewEngine.FindPartialView(fakeControllerContext, viewName, false);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(fakeControllerContext, razorViewResult.View, new ViewDataDictionary(model), new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
            razorViewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);
            return writer.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```