# How to parse a PartialView and return a Html string from ApiController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine, asp.net-apicontroller

I need to parse a `MVC` `PartialView` then convert it to plain html string and send it as `HttpResponseMessage` from `ApiController`.

Searching the web i found `RazorEngine` and i tried to use it unsuccessfully because it does not support `MVC` helpers like `@Html` or `@Styles.Render("~/css")` consequently was throwing me errors (following RazorEngine statement).

So is there any way to render a partial view from a `ApiController`?

[About RazorEngine](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/AboutRazor.html)

> **Razor vs. MVC vs. WebPages vs. RazorEngine**
>
> There is often a confusion about where Razor sits in this set of technologies. Essentially Razor is the parsing framework that does the work to take your text template and convert it into a compilable class. In terms of MVC and WebPages, they both utilise this parsing engine to convert text templates (view/page files) into executable classes (views/pages). Often we are asked questions such as "Where is @Html, @Url", etc. These are not features provided by Razor itself, but implementation details of the MVC and WebPages frameworks.
>
> RazorEngine is another consumer framework of the Razor parser. We wrap up the instantiation of the Razor parser and provide a common framework for using runtime template processing.

My code:

```
Func<string, string, object, HttpResponseMessage> renderTemplate = (templatePath, templateName, model) =>
{
    var viewPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(templatePath);
    var template = File.ReadAllText(viewPath);

    //Here throws error because it does not support MVC helpers like "@Html"
    var parsedTemplate = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, templateName, null, model);

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent(parsedTemplate) };
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return response;
};
```

I was calling the above function this way but of course it does not work:

```
renderTemplate(templatePath, "keyName", data);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you are able to resolve the assembly where the Html helper lives in the razor engine. The Html helper lives in the System.Web.Mvc.dll assembly (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx).  See https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ReferenceResolver.html for resolving assemblies.

Comment: It may be done in Web API just like in MVC. You can combine [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759898/4346368) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23504283/4346368) answers to get what you need. I've just tried it, it worked.