# Render View as String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Am trying to render a view as a string to be used as an email template. Am currently trying to implement this example:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/30/Rendering-ASPNET-MVC-Views-to-String

However am having difficulty with this section of code:

```
public ViewRenderer(ControllerContext controllerContext = null)
{
    // Create a known controller from HttpContext if no context is passed
    if (controllerContext == null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            controllerContext = CreateController<ErrorController>().ControllerContext;
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "ViewRenderer must run in the context of an ASP.NET " +
                "Application and requires HttpContext.Current to be present.");
    }
    Context = controllerContext;
}
```

Visual Studio is giving me the following error:

> "The type or namespace name 'ErrorController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Am probably missing something obvious but can't see what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an `ErrorController` in your project?

Comment: No, I wasn't sure if this was a standardised controller that could be added or if it was something I had to create.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to Render your view as a string, here is an extension method for the controller I wrote.

**NB: I will try and find the exact link I used to help me with this, and update my answer when I find it.**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494741/mvc-5-render-view-to-string) is another link, describing this method.

This should do the trick:

```
public static string RenderViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        var context = controller.ControllerContext;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, viewData, new TempDataDictionary(), sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

If you want to call this from a controller, you simply do the following:

```
var strView = this.RenderViewToString("YourViewName", yourModel);
```

Comment: Thanks, needed a couple of minor tweaks to work with my project but other did exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is there a way to set the encoding?  This works great on my enlish views, however, I also have some spanish views (utf8) and all of the characters with accents are rendered as encoded ansi, e.g. P&#243;ngase instead of Póngase.  I've tried setting globalization  fileEncoding="utf-8" in web.config and using a subclassed encoding textwriter without any luck.