# Render partial last in Razor page, despite being logically first

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a situation like so:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Header"); }

@{ Html.RenderPartial("ArbitraryView"); }
```

The `ArbitraryView` partial sets `ViewData["Test"]` in its view.

The `Header` partial *prints* `ViewData["Test"]`.

Is it possible to tell razor to render the `ArbitraryView` partial *first* in order for it to set `ViewData["Test"]`, then the `Header` last in order to read that value, without changing the order they're displayed on the page?

I am incapable of using `RenderBody`, which would achieve this desired result.

Comment: I would imagine so, but I can't prove it because that method is only available in ASP.NET Core

Comment: What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve?  It sounds like there is something seriously wrong with the structure of your code if a header view is dependent on another view rendered later.   If there is absolutely no way around this, could you just use JavaScript to "print" the value you're interested in when the page loads?  If you must really do this, render the partial views to a string and then output them with @Html.Raw() in the order you want.  See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051578/render-view-as-string)

Comment: It's not so much that I have a problem as it is just curiosity. I'm aware there's actual methods of postponing the execution of a method in a Razor view until the entire layout has been rendered, the [ClientDependency Framework](https://github.com/Shazwazza/ClientDependency) does this for example. Could you please also post that last sentence of your comment as an answer (_If you must really do this..._), as it's definitely a valid answer to my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `RenderPartial` you could use `Partial` and keep the results in variables. You can then output the results in the order you want:

```
@{ 
    var arbitraryView = Html.Partial("ArbitraryView");
    var header = Html.Partial("Header");
}

@header
@arbitraryView
```