# BUG not resolved yet, MVC 5 Partial View is rendering html tags in encoded format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Partial view is displaying in encoded format as :

```html
<$A$> <$B$>
<$C$>Title A<$D$>
```

How to avoid the `<$ $>` tags

Controller Action Method:

```html
 public PartialViewResult DetailsById(int? id)
        {

            CommunityAnnouncement communityAnnouncement = db.CommunityAnnouncements.Find(id);

            var html = PartialView("_Details", communityAnnouncement);
            return PartialView("_Details", communityAnnouncement);
        }
```

Parial View :

```html
@model CodeCactus.Models.CommunityAnnouncement

<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
```

Comment: from where you got this dollar sign?

Comment: Actually I also dont know where it came from. I was expecting normal html page but the result was with this 'dollar' sign.

Comment: Can you please check the title and description from the server?

Comment: @JEMI This is a know bug as said in [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794142/vs2013-preview-viewengineresult-render-returning-malformed-html), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387499/render-razor-view-to-string-without-munging-the-html?rq=1).

If I put debug to false in web.config, it is rendering properly [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx). Any solutions?